# How to automatically sum data per range of hour?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, for-loop

I'm pretty new at Python! So here's a rundown of what I'm doing (trying to do).

First, I wanted to convert seconds to hours. Then, for every data within a range of an hour, I'd like to sum those and find the mean.

so 1) I got this for the time :

```
hour = 0 
timesummed = [] 
#x axis, total 13 hours of daytime
for i in daytime["d"]:
    hour += i     
    timesummed.append(hour)
```

then I divided by 3600 seconds to make 13 hours

```
  daytime['seconds'] = timesummed
    daytime['hours'] = daytime['seconds']/3600
```

which works. However,

2. I want to add all the data and find the mean within the range of any given hour (for example, the data between 9th - 10th hour)

I got this :

```
liste = []
begin = 0 
mean= 0
for i in range(len(daytime['Sleep'])):
    if daytime["hours"][i]>9 and daytime["hours"][i]<10 and daytime["Sleep"] [i] != 0:
        begin += daytime["Sleep"][i]
        moyenne=begin/len(liste)
        if daytime["Sleep"] [i] == 0:  #ignores zero values (eg twitch)
            continue
        liste.append(begin)
print(begin/len(liste))
```

And this works too, but how to automatically get the mean for each hour? (in one go instead of manually putting the range)

Edit : Dataframe Daytime Sample :

| duration | activity | Sleep | Seconds | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201.902 | Sleep | 201.902 | 201.902 | 0.0560 |
| 5.4399 | Twitch | 0.0 | 207.341 | 0.0575 |
| 66.407 | Sleep | 66.407 | 273.749 | 0.076 |
| 0.240 | Walk Slowly | 0.0 | 1214.268 | 0.337 |
| 7.685 | Groom | 0.0 | 1241.492 | 0.345 |

(activities that weren't equal to the 'sleep' activity were put to zero so they aren't taken in account)

Comment: What is the [tag:pandas]/[tag:dataframe] aspect of this question?

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically"?

Comment: @ScottHunter Sorry, I meant all at once instead of manually

Comment: @HenryEcker they are using columns from the DataFrame `daytime` but @I_will_learn's current solution doesn't use any DataFrame or pandas functionality at the moment

Comment: @I_will_learn can you provide a sample of your DataFrame `daytime`? That would go a long way in making your code reproducible and also give us a better idea about what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: @DerekO There you go, Is that okay? I have over 8000 rows that span till 13 hours worth of data, so I'm not sure how much information is enough

Comment: Can you provide enough data to cover at least 2 hours (durations can be inflated so fewer rows are needed_, and show what you would expect this program to produce from that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please excuse me if I have misinterpreted your basic question, but it is a little hard to follow as written.
From what I can gather you have an initial dataframe **df** containing two columns *"duration"*, and *'activity'* which document sequential events over a 13 hour period and you desire to organize the data such that you can compute the mean of the activity on a per hour basis for each of the 13 hours. The initial dataframe is illustrated by the following example:
***Note:*** I have extended your initial example to provide a couple of hours of operation.
df :

```
    duration    activity
0   201.9020    Sleep
1   5.4399  Twitch
2   66.4070 Sleep
3   0.2400  Walk
4   7.6850  Groom
... ... ...
139 5.4399  Twitch
140 66.4070 Sleep
141 0.2400  Walk
142 7.6850  Groom
143 128.0000    Run
144 rows × 2 columns
```

```
# Compute event End Time
df['End_Time'] = df['duration'].cumsum()

# Compute Event Hour
df['Event_Hour'] = df.apply(lambda row: 1+int(row['End_Time']/3600)%24, axis= 1)
```

Then define a method to compute the average activity time by hour as

```
def compute_activity_mean(df, hr):
    #returns tuple containing (sleep_time, active_time, average_active_time)
    sleep_time = 0
    active_time = 0
    dfh = df[['duration', 'activity']].where(df['Event_Hour'] == 1).dropna()
    for i in range(dfh.shape[0]):
        if dfh.at[i, 'activity'] == 'Sleep':
            sleep_time += dfh.at[i, 'duration']
        else:
            active_time += dfh.at[i, 'duration']
    return  [sleep_time, active_time, active_time/(active_time+sleep_time)]
```

finally compute and display the average time per hourly increment by:

```
for hr in list(df["Event_Hour"].unique()):
    st, at, avgt = compute_activity_mean(df, hr)
    print(f'Hour: {hr}, Active Seconds: {at:.3f}, Sleep Seconds: {st:.3f}, Average Activity: {avgt:.3f}')
```

Which will yield something along the lines of the following depending on your data:

```
Hour: 1, Active Seconds: 1144.284, Sleep Seconds: 2414.781, Average Activity: 0.322
Hour: 2, Active Seconds: 1144.284, Sleep Seconds: 2414.781, Average Activity: 0.322
Hour: 3, Active Seconds: 1144.284, Sleep Seconds: 2414.781, Average Activity: 0.322
```

Comment: Thank you! I'd upvote but I don't have the reputation to. This was very helpful!!

Comment: I don't have the reputation to upvote your answer :( I need my questions to be upvoted to get 10+ reputation

Comment: you were right, sorry! It's accepted now :)

Comment: No problem it's a learning process for us all